# Problems with replacing XML tag contents using sed

Tags: bash, sed, xml, hashsum

I have the following XML piece:

```
<value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">+380554446363</value>
<value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">+380554446364</value>
<value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">+380554446365</value>
```

I am trying to replace the `<value>` tag contents with their SHA-1 hashes using the following command:

```
cat test.xml | sed "s/>[+]\([0-9][0-9]*\)<\/value>/>+$(echo \\1 | sha1sum | cut -f1 -d' ')<\/value>/g"
```

It fails by replacing all found cases with the same incorrect value.

Expected:

```
<value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">34df370575e3528b31daef8633cb539119a3b028</value>
<value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">d93767c769fd51bcf9eb25f95932559b24bae812</value>
<value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">20338c1f048bed553b6cce76eaf1d388ba7686f5</value>
```

Got:

```
<value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">+cbcac786fef5abeb39fe473ab6abe554978a8156</value>
<value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">+cbcac786fef5abeb39fe473ab6abe554978a8156</value>
<value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">+cbcac786fef5abeb39fe473ab6abe554978a8156</value>
```

What could I be doing wrong? TIA.

Comment: This would be easier if the XML was well-formed. It's currently missing a root node and the `values` nodes lacks its end tag. Should we just improvise those bits?

Comment: Yes, the only lines that actually matter are the ones with the `<value>` tag. I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: Do you realise that your SHA checksums are all incorrect? They hash not only the value but also a trailing newline

Comment: I completely missed that, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sha1sum` is evaluating the SHA-1 of the constant string "\\1" instead of the first SED regex match:

```
$ echo \\1 | sha1sum
cbcac786fef5abeb39fe473ab6abe554978a8156  -
```

The shell performs all the various expansions (e.g. command substitutions) before executing the command (in this case, sed). Thus, shell expands

```
cat test.xml | sed "s/>[+]\([0-9][0-9]*\)<\/value>/>+$(echo \\1 | sha1sum | cut -f1 -d' ')<\/value>/g"
```

to

```
cat test.xml | sed "s/>[+]\([0-9][0-9]*\)<\/value>/>+cbcac786fef5abeb39fe473ab6abe554978a8156<\/value>/g"
```

It then runs two processes, one running

```
cat test.xml
```

and another running

```
sed "s/>[+]\([0-9][0-9]*\)<\/value>/>+cbcac786fef5abeb39fe473ab6abe554978a8156<\/value>/g"
```

with the STDOUT of the first process piped to the STDIN of the second process.

In order for what you're trying to do to work, `sed` would have to be able to execute other executables from within `sed`. I don't believe `sed` can do that, so you'll have to do it some other way.

You can do it using `sed`, e.g. this is one way

```
for a in `cat test.xml | sed -E 's,^.*>(\+[0-9]+)<\/value>$,\1,'`; do echo "$a" | sha1sum | cut -f1 -d' '; done >2nd
cat test.xml | sed -E 's,>\+[0-9]+</value>$,>,' >1st
paste -d '' 1st 2nd | sed -E 's,$,</value>,'
```

You've also not included the "+" in the brackets enclosing the first `sed` match string, from the SHA1 sums you've provided as the expected results, I believe you want the "+" included, so I've corrected that as well.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to answer more of my questions than I was able to figure out so far. However, I notice that, when running `cat test.xml | sed "s/>[+]\([0-9][0-9]*\)<\/value>/>+$(echo \\1)<\/value>/g"` (without piping the result to `sha1sum`), it seems to process the backreference correctly and outputs not the constant string "\\1" but the actual matched values, unmodified. What could be the case here?

Answer (score 4):

Don't edit XML with `sed` or `awk`. Use a proper `xml` parser, e.g. python's `xml.etree`:

`input.xml`:

```xml
<values>
    <value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">+380554446363</value>
    <value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">+380554446364</value>
    <value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">+380554446365</value>
</values>
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import hashlib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for value in root:
    value.text = hashlib.sha256(value.text.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()


tree.write('output.xml')
```

`output.xml`:

```xml
<values>
    <value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">4b2bdff20d17dc4ae7ad99937399530b39bd7a63f7348375c547d01565c11898</value>
    <value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">8d3b1452d83ef803f8043eaddbe2fc58b0fd42c8ad5abc554e78796548f75ddb</value>
    <value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">06bd986417875e536401306180c51b7ded4eeab179933e0026a103bc8dc9eee7</value>
</values>
```

Comment: In normal circumstances I would be doing that but, unfortunately, in this particular case I have to solve it using just `sed`.

Comment: Does that module do `sha1` too, as the question does not seem want to use `sha256`.

Comment: It does, although it's not really relevant in my case.

Comment: "in this particular case I have to solve it using just sed". No you don't. As a professional, you should insist on using the proper tools for the job.

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed substitute command has an `/e`
modifier which executes as vash code, the rhs of the s/// aka, the modified pattern space.

```
sed -E "
  s/'/&\\\\&&/g
  s:(<.*>)([+][0-9]+)(</value>.*):printf '%s%s%s' '\\1' \"\$(echo '\\2'|sha1sum|cut -d' ' -f1)\" '\\3':e
" test.xml

<value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">34df370575e3528b31daef8633cb539119a3b028</value>
<value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">d93767c769fd51bcf9eb25f95932559b24bae812</value>
<value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">20338c1f048bed553b6cce76eaf1d388ba7686f5</value>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a system with an [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) compiled with `crypto`
[extension](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/extensions.html) functions you
could say:

```sh
xmlstarlet sel -N crypto='http://exslt.org/crypto' \
  -t -m '//value' -e '{name()}' -c '@*' -v 'crypto:sha1(.)' -b -n \
file.xml
```

Output:

```
<value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">3bacaac1e104d7bfde5ff462d461d3b4b917c037</value>
<value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">808b3e7bb8c8c7c06c328a082bac64205837531b</value>
<value id="1" creatorId="0" creationTime="1639487132" expirationTime="1639573532">8c31811a3b8d816f719ad5c78b58810b9b6cd4b7</value>
```

where the checksums differ from the desired output as they're not
computed from texts including newlines.

---

Running `xmlstarlet transform --show-ext 2>&1 | grep crypto` at my end
outputs:

```
{http://exslt.org/crypto}md4
{http://exslt.org/crypto}sha1
{http://exslt.org/crypto}md5
{http://exslt.org/crypto}rc4_decrypt
{http://exslt.org/crypto}rc4_encrypt
```